# Do extra electrons ever stay on the P side of a diode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

When electrons move from the N side to the P side, it fills in the holes on the P side.

Question 1. Do the holes remain filled after the circuit is turned off?

Question 2. While the holes are filled during use or while the diode is not in use, do atoms on the P side ever gain an electron in addition to the hole being filled?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "circuit turned off", what circumstances "electrons move from the N side to the P side" and the entirety of question 2? I think you are very confused about how diodes work, and semiconductors in general. Expanding on these will help provide a useful answer.

Comment: Basically, if you use the diode, are the holes in the P side filled with electrons when it's no longer in use.

Comment: You really need to consider electrons and holes on the same footing, and understand their dynamic relationship through detailed balance.

Answer (score -1):

Answer 1. No. Once the circuit is turned off the holes become empty and n side will have "extra electrons".
Answer 2. When in use, the electrons travel by jumping from hole to hole. So, yes, the atoms get an extra electron while in use.

The important thing to remember here is the charge in the nucleus. The "hole" and "extra electron" are merely related to covalent bond, not about net charge of the atom. The net charge must be zero when not energized. So, when a diode is used in a circuit (turned-on), the atoms are energized. That is why the n side atoms can release a charge and p side atoms can accept an extra charge. But when turned off, the atoms lose their energy source and cannot remain energized. So, the atoms must return to a charge neutral state.

Comment: I think I get it. So the atoms in the P type are charge neutral even with the holes? That's where my confusion was. I thought the holes were counted as being positive. Thank you sir.

Comment: This answer is wrong on both counts. 1) The depletion region exists whether or not the circuit is turned on, although the size can vary. 2) Electrons do not move by jumping through holes. Holes and electrons are both their own quasiparticles that move all on their own and electrons and holes are not localized to individual atoms.

Comment: Let's hear your answer @Matt

Comment: @Jason I would love to, but the question is confusing and I cant tell what is being asked.

Comment: How can you not, tbf? When the diode is used, do the holes on the P side fill and do they stay filled when it's not in use?

Comment: @Matt. He is asking from rudimentary level not at expert level. Think of it like explaining to high school students about how diode works.